# Want to show pdf name on a webpage without its extention

Tags: php, string

I want to show uploaded pdf on the webpage. The name of pdf comes from the database with a timestamp. How to show only that pdf name without a timestamp and extention? Here is my code but it is not generating required output.

```
$count = strlen($promotion_data->pdf1);
$pos=strrpos($promotion_data->pdf1,"_");
$poz = $count - $pos;
$SavePath=substr($promotion_data->pdf1,0,$poz);//name to echo
```

file-name in db is *Beginning-Zend-Framework_1399126117.pdf*.

Comment: Show us example $promotion_data->pdf1 content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it should work:

```
$ext = pathinfo($promotion_data->pdf1, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$pos=strrpos($promotion_data->pdf1,"_");
$SavePath=substr($promotion_data->pdf1,0,$pos).'.'.$ext; //name to echo
```

If your file names have non ASCII letters and symbols you should also set valid encoding as for example

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

and use mb_substr and mb_strrpos insted of substr and strrpos

Comment: Show us variable content

Comment: It makes thos function are working with special characters as for example ą, ę and so on. If your file has such characters in name standard functions strpos, substr and similar won't work properly. Look at http://au1.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: I don't know if I understood rights, you also want extension be displayed so I changed the code in answer